# My code will not read and display data from a file using ifstream and ofstream

Tags: c++

While my data is put into the file named based on the user's input of "myfile", when I go to read and display it in the else statement, the name shows up as "", the balance is 0, and the file data is deleted.

We just learned `fstream` and its commands in my C++ class yesterday.  Still new to using it.  The teacher said that using `getline(inputfile, name)` and `inputfile >> balance` should read the data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

string myfile;
int balance = 0;
string name;

cout << "Enter your first name." << endl;
getline (cin, myfile);

ifstream inputfile(myfile);
ofstream outputfile(myfile);

if ( ! inputfile.good() )
{
        cout << "Enter your FIRST and LAST name." << endl;
        getline(cin, name);
        outputfile << name << endl;
        cout << "Hello " << name << endl;

        cout << "Enter your initial balance." << endl;
        cin >> balance;
        outputfile << balance << endl;
}
else
{
        getline(inputfile, name);
        cout << "Welcome Back" << name << endl;
        cout << "Here is a log of all your BALANCE activity." << endl;

       inputfile >> balance;
       cout << "Your balance is " << balance << endl;
}

outputfile.close();
inputfile.close();

return 0;
}
```

it should read the data from the file and display the full name as well as the balance integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer is doing exactly what you told it to do.

```
getline (cin, myfile);
```

Get some text from the user and store it in `myFile`.

```
ifstream inputfile(myfile);
```

Open the file named by `myFile` for reading (if it exists).

```
ofstream outputfile(myfile);
```

Open the same file you just opened, but this time for writing. [If the file exists, destroy its contents. If the file does not exist, create it.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)

Then you proceed to the `if` statement. If the file had existed, you proceed to the `else` clause. There you discover that the contents of the file have been destroyed. Not a surprise, since that is the default behavior when `ofstream` opens an existing file.

What you probably want to do is move the declaration of `outputfile` into the `if` statement so that it is only hit when the file does not exist.

```
if ( ! inputfile.good() )
{
        ofstream outputfile(myfile);

        cout << "Enter your FIRST and LAST name." << endl;
        getline(cin, name);
        outputfile << name << endl;
        cout << "Hello " << name << endl;

        cout << "Enter your initial balance." << endl;
        cin >> balance;
        outputfile << balance << endl;
        // No need to explicitly close the file, as the destructor will handle that.
}
else
{
    // etc.
```